# Learning Java from a C# background

Tags: c#, java

For complicated reasons (not C#'s fault I love that language very much) I have to learn Java. I hate learning new langages and i dont wanna have to learn what I already know from C#.

What are some resources that teach whats different without learning it all?

Comment: I am also in the same boat as you. Last i heard Java was still in the 2000s

Comment: "I hate learning new languages" strikes me as a really odd thing to say if you're developer.

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen
what i mean is i get frustrated by not being able to do simple things i can do easily in other languages.

Comment: @shorty876: Fair enough, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this isn't a very specific answer, but the best advice I can give you is to not go into it with the "I hate learning new languages" mindset.  If you're familiar with C#, Java will be a piece of cake.  Depending on what you're working on, most of your questions can easily be answered by a quick look at the API documentation.  I don't think you have to worry about "learning it all".

Answer (score 0):

The problem won't be the syntax but the framework. Since I'm not a Java developer either, I'm not sure where to look. But I suggest looking into the frameworks you'll be working with instead of syntax.